# How to access family details in facebook using facebook graph api?

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, access-token

This is my code in getting the family details:

```
<?php


if ($user) {
  try {

    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $family = $facebook->api('/me/family'); 

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
      error_log($e);
      $user = null;
    }

  print_($family);

  }



  ?>
```

But it will display

```
   Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

And also i would like to get their profile pictures together with their details. thanks

Comment: Ensure that user must have given user_relationships permission to access details.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your User Access Token have granted **user_relationships** permission.

[image]